# Java - Spacing for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I cannot post my Java questions to Stack Overflow, because it keeps complaining about four space indenting. I've manually inserted five spaces on my code, and yet Stack Overflow is still complaining.

I am ready to give up. It's kind of hard to get answers if you can't post a question. I am altering my indenting to satisfy Stack Overflow, but it still won't let me post. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what exactly your problem is? SO identifies code as text that has an indentation of at least 4 spaces. You can shortcut this by selecting the text and hitting `CTRL+K` or using the corresponding button of the editor-UI.

Comment: You can always copy and paste your code it, then highlight it and click the `{}` button at the top of the editor. That will add in four additional spaces at the start of each line.

Comment: In particular, be specific about the error message you're getting. Is the problem perhaps that your question consists *only* of code? We can't tell at the moment...

Comment: I'm going to vote to delete this, as it is embarrassing.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you need a preceding newline before the codeblock along with the 4 space indentation e.g.

```
someCode();
```